Присваивание роли определенному пользователю по ID sqlalchemy
как сделать обновление определенного статуса (в моем случае true/false) в базе данных sqlalchemy? Мой код  обновляет статус всем юзерам, а нужно только тому, кто логинится именно с айди == 1
PYTHON

@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    login = request.form.get('login')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    if login and password:
        user = User.query.filter_by(login=login).first()

        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            login_user(user)
        
            next_page = request.args.get('next', 1)

            if user.id == 1:
                db.session.query(User).filter(User.admin == user.admin).update({User.admin : True})
                db.session.commit()
            else:
                pass

            return redirect(next_page)
        else:
            flash('Неправильный логин или пароль')
    else:
        flash('Пожалуйста заполните поля авторизации')

    return render_template('login.html')


Класс модели (если нужен)
class User (db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)


В чём вообще смысл данного кода? Зачем пытаться менять admin в момент логина?

о, здравствуйте еще раз) я пытаюсь дать статус админа первому пользователю, тк им всегда будет мой аккаунт, а потом уже он будет раздавать всем дальше.

Ну давайте в момент создания первого пользователя, зачем в момент логина-то?

А в момент создания первого пользователя у меня еще нет аккаунта, с которого я бы смог получить айди

Не вижу проблемы в том, чтобы написать точно такой же if user.id == 1: в функции регистрации вместо функции логина

Сейчас попробую, но он все равно будет изменять всем пользователям, но уже при регистрации новых аккаунтов, нет?

Я сначала так и сделал, но выдало ошибку

Ну а независимо от этого — думайте, что вы пишете в запросах к БД: написав .filter(User.admin == user.admin), вы просите БД вернуть всех пользователей, у которых значение столбца User.admin совпадает со значением переменной user.admin — и если user.admin имеет значение False, то значит этот запрос вернёт всех не-админов. А если вы хотите получить юзера с id 1, значит так и нужно писать .filter(User.id == 1) — но, как я уже писал вчера, вы уже получили юзера в переменную user и уже проверили, что id у него 1, вы можете менять user напрямую и нет смысла делать ещё один запрос в БД

db.session.user.update({User.admin : True}) ?

Для начала какая у вас версия sqlalchemy?

SQLAlchemy==2.0.31

Все, я нашел ошибку. Нужно по чаще принт использовать. Спасибо вам, вы очень помогаете мне

Только как это делать без фильтра через уже готового юзера?

Так, а какая у вас версия Flask-SQLAlchemy? Ваш код сильно отличается от того, что я вижу в документации актуальной версии

Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1, актуальная

А, там ещё Legacy Quickstart и Legacy Query Interface есть... Думаю, вы излишне усложняете себе жизнь, используя устаревшие интерфейсы в новых версиях, но да ладно уже

Спасибо, я ознакомлюсь

Не-не, ознакамливаться надо с не-легаси) https://flask-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/quickstart/ — https://flask-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/queries/

Ну а раз уж легаси — насколько я могу видеть — объекты, полученные из БД, автоматически отслеживаются сессией на предмет изменений, соответственно сделать user.admin = True с последующим db.session.commit() вроде должно быть достаточно
